# How can I link to a specific section in the Oxford English Dictionary, OED?

Tags: oed.com

The recent redesign to the OED (Oxford English Dictionary) website has changed the entire interface so I’m not sure where anything is anymore.

I want to be able to create a link to a specific subsense or even a specific quotation, regardless of their tab settings. What about on tabs other than “*Meaning & use*”, like the Notes section under “*Etymology*”?

---

Here is a link to a free page as an example: [they (PRONOUN, ADJECTIVE, ADVERB, & NOUN)](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/they_pron)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be to copy the link from the left sidebar (accessed via the [top left hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uViMA.png) or "Browse entry" on mobile), which allows you to get links to even the third third level subsense: https://www.oed.com/dictionary/they_pron?tab=meaning_and_use&show-all-quotations=true#18520139 (this link was copied with the "show all quotations" checkbox selected). Make sure you are on tabbed view first, since some links on the non-tabbed page don’t transfer properly. For example, https://www.oed.com/dictionary/they_pron?tab=forms#288561675 will work with tabs or no tabs, since the section it points to is on the forms tab, which is in the URL, but the tabbed view will have “meaning_and_use” instead, which only works in the non-tabbed view.

Using “Cite” under a section will get you a DOI link (e.g., https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/1483149844) that redirects to there, but it will lose any URL parameters (like the one to show all quotations). Note that some sections (e.g., those under “Forms”) only have sidebar links.

Some parts of the entry cannot be linked to unless you do so at the browser level. In Chrome (browser or mobile), you can highlight text and “copy link to highlight”: [https://www.oed.com/dictionary/they_pron?tab=meaning_and_use#18520139:~:text=In%20the%20whilke%20visyon%20er%20fulle%20many%20comfortabylle%20wordes%20and%20gretly%20styrrande](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/they_pron?tab=meaning_and_use#18520139:%7E:text=In%20the%20whilke%20visyon%20er%20fulle%20many%20comfortabylle%20wordes%20and%20gretly%20styrrande). Again, make sure you’re in tabbed view to prevent any issues with the URL.